# T-SQL to LINQ Query (Many to Many filter)

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have Enquiries that have a Many to 1 with Clients. Enquiries also have a Many To Many to DisabilityCodes. What I'd like to do is collect all the unique clients that have enquiries that contain a certain disability code. This is my T-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientId FROM (
   SELECT ce.Id as EnquiryId, dc.Code, c.Id as ClientId
      FROM ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCodes as etd
      INNER JOIN DisabilityCodes as dc
      ON etd.ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCode_DisabilityCode = dc.Id
      INNER JOIN ClientEnquiries as ce
      ON etd.ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCode_ClientEnquiry = ce.Id
      INNER JOIN Clients as c 
      ON ce.ClientEnquiry_Client = c.Id
      WHERE dc.Code = 'Ast') 
AS data
```

Could someone even start to show me how to turn this into LINQ? I'm not even sure where to start. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't as difficult as I first thought. I should probably drink MORE coffee before starting to work!

```
var distinctcients = (from etd in Context.ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCodes
                                  join dc in Context.DisabilityCodes on etd.ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCode_DisabilityCode equals dc.Id
                                  join ce in Context.ClientEnquiries on etd.ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCode_ClientEnquiry equals ce.Id
                                  join c in Context.Clients on ce.ClientEnquiry_Client equals c.Id
                                  where dc.Code == DisabilityCode
                                  select c.Id)
                                 .Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the class structure attached below, the `Example` method will achieve what you're attempting

```
void Example()
{
    var clients = new DisabilityCode[1].Where(dc      => dc.Code == "Ast")
                                       .SelectMany(dc => dc.Enquiries)
                                       .Select(etd    => etd.ClientEnquiry)
                                       .Select(ce     => ce.Client.ClientId);
                                    //     or
                                    // .Select(ce     => ce.Client)
                                    // .Select(c      => c.ClientId);

}

public class DisabilityCode
{
    public string DisabilityId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCode> Enquiries { get; set; }
}

public class ClientEnquiry
{
    public string ClientEnquiryId { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCode DisabilityCode { get; set; }
}

public class ClientEnquiryToDisabilityCode
{
    public string ClientEnquiryId { get; set; }
    public string DisabilityCodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ClientEnquiry ClientEnquiry { get; set; }
    public virtual DisabilityCode DisabilityCode { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientEnquiry> Enquiries { get; set; }
}
```